# scss output separate files

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, output

I want to write this in one file:

```
body {

background: #FFF;

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
         background: #DDD;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        background: #CCC;
    }

}
```

And want to output into two separate files, first layout.css

```
body { background: #FFF; }
```

and second media-queries.css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    background: #DDD;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    background: #CCC;
}
```

What I must to do?

Thanks

Comment: What would be the purpose of breaking out *all* of the media queries into one file?

Answer (score 0):

SASS provides handy tools to merge multiple source files into one or several resulting files, but it does not provide any facilities to split them.

Also, as cimmanon already mentioned, your goal just does not make sense. It might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If it is, please explain the original problem, not your solution to it. If it is not, just don't split the CSS file.